# How to change the aLengthMenu of DataTables after it has been initialized

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a DataTable which is initialized with the default settings. However, I want to change the default aLengthMenu which has value as [10,25,50,100] to my custom value.

After doing some research, I found that using API of Datatables it can be done. I also looked at some similar approach on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

This is what I have tried. I am using 1.10.x version of DataTable.

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable();
table.settings().context[0]._iDisplayLength  = 10;
table.settings().context[0].aLengthMenu = [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]];
table.draw();
```

Comment: why are you not doing it like it shows here https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html ?

Comment: For some functionality reason I need to initialize it with default settings only. Is there any way I can change the setting using API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     try this: http://jsbin.com/moyonos/edit?js,output   


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable({pageLength:25,"lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
                data: someData.data,
                "columns": [
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "position" },
                { "data": "office" },
                { "data": "extn" },
                { "data": "start_date" },
                { "data": "salary" }

                                        ]
            });

             // name of table + "_length"
             var $sel =$("#example_length select");

            $sel.html("<option value='3'>3</option>");
            $sel.append("<option value='6'>6</option>");
            $sel.append("<option value='9'>9</option>");
            $sel.append("<option value='12'>12</option>");
            $sel.append("<option value='15'>15</option>");
            $sel.append("<option value='-1'>All</option>");

            $sel.trigger("change");
        });
```

Comment: since the datatable has been already initialized, you probably cant change the settings and have it show up in the dropdown.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks Bindrid :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#table').DataTable({
      pageLength:10,  
     "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ]});
```

I have  working example here: http://jsbin.com/dibuga/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: This works fine. However I need to change the settings after it has been initialized. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: I think I found a solution, give me a couple minutes to test it